# How can I programatically add an image inside a TListBoxItem?

Tags: android, ios, image, delphi, listbox

### Problem

For a long time, I was using a Custom Style to load a detailed `TListBox`.

It's basically a `ListBox` with a `TImage` as an icon.

However recently I've been encountering lots of bugs and decided to throw it all away.

This is how I generate my `TListBox` items programatically:

```
   // Create LISTBox Item
   lb_item        := TListBoxItem.Create(self);
   lb_item.Parent := lb_awesome_list;
   lb_item.Text   := cow_name;
```

What if I would like to add an `Image` to it?

### What I have done so far

I've tried to add it as an ItemData

```
lb_item.ItemData.Bitmap := iv_user_ic.Bitmap;
```

And a few other options without success. Is it possible to add an image programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach with setting the `ItemData.Bitmap` property is a good start. Now you have to select an appropriate item style to show the bitmap. F.i. *listboxitemleftdetail* should do.

Comment: Yay! I was missing the `lb_item.StyleLookup            := 'listboxitemleftdetail';` indeed. Thank you, @Raabe.