# FMX ListBoxItem with ItemData.Bitmap issue on XE 10.1 Berlin

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, listboxitem

I have interesting issue. I recompiling FMX application from XE7 to XE10.1
I Have form with ListBox and I dynamicaly creating TListBoxItem in code.

`var
 Item: TListBoxItem;
 begin
      Item := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);
      Item.Parent := ListBox1;
      Item.StyleLookup := 'listboxitemnodetail';
      Item.Height:=50;
      Item.WordWrap:=true;
      Item.Text := 'abc';
      Item.ItemData.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('img.bmp')
end;`

But Image in ListBox item not show. This issue is only on Delphi XE 10.1 Berlin.
On Delphi XE7 it works fine.

If I generate ListBoxItem manualy in IDE code works fine

Where can be problem ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35880064/2292722) to the same question, except unclear if it concerns XE 10.1 Berlin, suggests using `listboxitemleftdetail` style lookup.

Comment: I tested it but result is same - image not show

Answer (score 3):

Issue fixed !

In XE10 is necessary set StyleLookup after Bitmap Load !